# Where do these white lines come from?

Tags: html, css

Have a look at this link: [LINK](http://dharman.eu/box/)

As you can see it's a matrix of red divs 20x20(px) in size each. THere should be no space between them but there are white lines between rows. I pressume it's because I used `display:inilne-block;`. Is there any other way to do this? Why do they appear there in a first place?

```
.red {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red;
    border: 0 none;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0 none;
    padding: 0;
    width: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `float` will work, because declaring that also silently sets the display property to `block` (see image below from the Chrome inspector:

[image: Chrome inspector]

The gap you're seeing is because you are using `inline-block`. It is (I believe) the space reserved for descenders on letters such as 'p' and 'q'. The key is the `vertical-align` property, which by default is set to `baseline`. If you set that to something else (`top`, `bottom`), then the gap will be removed (see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/tLnsw/)).

So, use `float` if that suits your purposes, but if you need the other benefits of `inline-block`, then use that with a declared vertical alignment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F00;
border: 0 none;
display: block;
height: 20px;
line-height: 0;
margin: 0;
outline: 0 none;
padding: 0;
width: 20px;
float: left;
```

Change the display attr. to block and float to left!